# Почему выводится menu-1

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
register_nav_menus( array(
            'menu-1' => 'Меню в футере',
            'menu-top' => 'Меню в вверху',
            'menu-3' => 'Меню в шапке',
        ) );
```

Регистрация меню

```
    wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => 'menu-top', 
    'container'       => 'div', 
    'container_class' => '', 
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => '',
) );
```

Вывод меню

Но выводится всеравно menu-1!!!

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, menu-top - это область темы, а в ней задано menu-1.

Так примерно выглядит управление областями меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понял

Comment: menu=0&use-location=menu-top

Comment: Можно по подробней?

Comment: Добавил картинку в ответ